# Javascript XML Library

Tags: javascript, xml, frameworks

I am looking for a standardized way to handle XML in a Javascript/HTML application.

The operations I need to perform regarding XML are the following :

- Producing programmatically XML documents

  - Creation of new document
  - Creation of elements / attributes, text nodes, and CDATA
  - Conversion of XML documents to strings (for subsequent use in HTTP request)
- Parsing XML documents

  - Creating documents from a strings
  - Querying the XML documents (à la "XPath")

I am looking for a solution / library with the following qualities:

- Symmetrical (single library for both reading and writing)
- Safety regarding characters encoding
- Cross-browser support
- Namespace and prefix mapping support

Thanks.

Comment: Uhm, what about the standard dom-api?

Comment: AFAIK, jQuery fits well XML some of the parsing needs, but is relatively weak concerning the ability to "generate" XML.

Answer (score 0):

How about the native DOM?

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.implementation
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535865(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I am not sure how consistent is the support for features such as XPath on the different browsers.